# How to get data from Wordpress database?

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to get a row out of a table (`gc_test`) I created in my Wordpress database. I have read the Wordpress documentation and followed it exactly and still no joy.

The `$results` array never seems to get populated.

```
$results = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->gc_test WHERE coupon_code = $code, ARRAY_A");

if($results['redeemable']=="true"){
    $message = "Code is good!";
}
else{
    $message = "Code has already been redeemed!";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you are referring to your custom table is not correct. The correct way is to `global $wpdb`  and the `prefix` property. The way that you have `$code` embedded is also not correct for a few reasons - it is likely a string and should be surrounded by single quotes, but no matter what is likely a potential SQL injection vulnerability. Make sure to use `$wpdb->prepare()` to pass arguments with placeholders of `%s` for strings and `%d` for digits. You also have the double quotes in the wrong place - it is including `ARRAY_A` in with your SQL rather than as an argument to `get_rows()`.

```
// declare $wpdb.
global $wpdb;
// sql string using $wpdb->prefix and %s placeholder
$sql = "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}gc_test WHERE coupon_code = %s";
// pass the sql into prepare()
$query = $wpdb->prepare( $sql, $coupon_code );
// call get_row() and tell it that you want an associative array back
$row = $wpdb->get_row( $query, ARRAY_A );

if ( empty( $row ) ){
    // nothing came back from the db
    $message = "Code not found.";
} elseif ( isset( $row['redeemable'] ) && $row['redeemable'] == "true" ){
    // we got a row and it was redeemable
    $message = "Code is good!";
} else {
    // something else
    $message = "Code has already been redeemed!";
}
```

Comment: gc is not my WP database prefix. All of the tables are prefixed with the default wp_ and only this one table I created manually has the gc_ affixed to it.

Also, I did declare $wpdb I just failed to list it here apologies.

Could you give a bit more insight as to sql injections happening on a get call. I naively assumed if you are reading only it should be relatively safe.

Comment: I am able to make an update call using the gc_test name to target that table. I don't see where the table is specified in the above code.

Comment: In that case you would use `{$wpdb->prefix}gc_test` which will translate to `wp_gc_test`. SQL injection literally means what it says - you might want it to be a SELECT, but I can inject something else into the middle of it. Using `prepare()` protects against this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to doublesharp's post I went back and studies the $wpdb->prefix function. Apparently this is pretty important. So I changed my prefix on the table from gc_ to wp_ and then assigned the table to a variable with: {$wpdb->prefix}test and it now works like a charm. Thanks a ton!